# Is it possible to run Falcon app from Python?

Tags: python, gunicorn, falconframework, falcon

I'm moving my code from Flask to Falcon and a small annoyance is that I can't seem to find way to run my Falcon-based app from the `__main__` method. In my Flask app I had this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=os.getenv('PORT', 5000))
```

Is there a way to do the same for the Falcon app? I don't mind to use a wrapper like Gunicorn but that one also seems to not run (easily) from the `__main__` as well

*Note: This is strictly for development purposes, I know how to run the Falcon app in production*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure use [`wsgiref`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wsgiref.html), e.g.:

```
from wsgiref import simple_server

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with simple_server.make_server('', os.getenv('PORT', 5000), app) as httpd:
        httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Fantastic! This is exactly what I was looking for!